# Algorithm of array shuffle with distance restriction

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, permutation, shuffle

For example, I have the following array:

```
array numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

I want to shuffle this array. But there is one distance restriction: new position of each element must be from `old_position - n` to `old_position + n`.

For example, if `n = 4`, then this array is good for me:

```
array new_numbers = {2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7}
```

I tried to think of some algorithm. But I did not succeed.

Comment: What distribution do you want?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, I would like a uniform distribution.

Comment: How large can `n` be?

Comment: There are 9 elements in the first array and 10 in the second, so this isn't what I would call a shuffle.  Also it's not clear what n is -- is it a free parameter whose value we are given?

Comment: David Eisenstat, there is no some restriction for n.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I am sorry, I made typo. Both arrays have 10 elements. `n` is free parameter.

Comment: Does the solution have to be in place ?

Comment: @Rerito, there is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some pseudo code that may help. Note that the algorithm is focused on conforming to the distance rule, sacrificing uniformity* in the process.

```
choose a random array index (call it "i" )
there's number at array[i] (call it "A")
set "count" to 0
for each "j" such that array[j] is a valid location for "A"
{
    there's a number at array[j] (call it "B")
    if ( "B" can be legally moved to array[i] )
        increment "count" 
}
generate a random number between 0 and count-1
find the index "j" that corresponds to that random number
swap array[i] with array[j]

repeat the above sequence a satisfactory number of times
```

<sub>* Seems to me that the problem definition requires a non-uniform distribution, since for example, the values at the start and end of the array have fewer legal positions than the values in the middle of the array. So trying to develop an algorithm that's provably uniform seems like a fool's errand.</sub>

Comment: yeah, you're right. It is my fault. Indeed, the distribution is not uniform.

Comment: If you don't keep track of the swapped indexes, you can end up with cascading shuffles, e.g. "swap(1,3) ... swap(3, 6)" (assuming `n=4`). In the end, `1` gets at `6` and has moved more than it should.

Comment: @Rerito I'm assuming that the starting array has the number `i` at index `i`, so you can always tell which indexes are valid just by looking at the number. Therefore, after "swap(1,3)" it won't be legal to do "swap(3,6)", since the `valid locations for "1"` will be 0 thru 5. In other words, the loop `for each "j"...` will be `for j in 0 thru 5`.

Comment: That assumption is only based on the OP's example. I think there is no such criterion, it was just more convenient to build an example using this particular case. When thinking of a solution, we should not make that assumption.

Comment: @Rerito Yes, if the assumption is invalid, then I would create a shadow array that does have the property that `array[i] == i`. Then shuffle the shadow array, while at the same time performing identical swaps on the actual array.

Comment: My thought exactly, that's why I asked if the solution has to be in place ... Waiting for the answer :). (I would perform the swaps once the shadow array is shuffled, not at each step)

Comment: Input array is a random. In general, `array[i] == i` rule is not satisfied.

Comment: @Max, that's the point. You build an array that satisfies this condition. You shuffle it, then you use it to shuffle the target array.